# Variables de entorno Cypress

Tags: javascript

Quiero acceder a mi página de login. Para montar la URL añado el localhost en el archivo .env.json y en el archivo de test agrego el resto de la URL para asi cuando haga más páginas pues poder reutilizar mi variable de entorno y no tener que estar ingresando siempre el localhost

CYPRESS.ENV.JSON

```
{
  "api_server": "http://localhost:8080/"
}
```

TEST.JS

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Visits the app root url', () => {
    cy.request(Cypress.env('api_server'))
    cy.visit('auth/login')
    // cy.visit(Cypress.env('api_server'+'/auth/login'))
  })
})
```

ERROR QUE EMITE LA CONSOLA

```
CypressError: cy.visit() failed trying to load:

auth/login

We failed looking for this file at the path:

/Users/fronts/front_base/auth/login

The internal Cypress web server responded with:

  > 404: Not Found
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado

```
describe('Testeamos el acceso al Login', () => {
     it('si accedo a mi perfil sin estar registrado, me redirecciona al login', () => {
       cy.visit(Cypress.env('api_server')+'auth/login')
     })
   })
```